# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() when using KerasClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I want to build a logistic regression model using Keras and train with X epochs. I want to obtain the accuracy and loss scores from the model.
My code raised `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`. However, `X_train[cv_train]` and `y_train[cv_train]` are not `NoneType`.

Code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=1) 

def build_logistic_regression_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=1,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='sigmoid',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.)))
    
    # Performance visualization callback
    performance_viz_cbk = PerformanceVisualizationCallback(model=model,validation_data=X_val,dat_dir='c:\performance_charts')
    
    model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model

lrscores = []
train_lrscores = []
for cv_train, cv_val in kfold.split(X_train, y_train):
    lr_model_logit = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_logistic_regression_model, batch_size = 10)    
    hist = lr_model_logit.fit(X_train[cv_train], y_train[cv_train], epochs=200).history_
    losses = hist["mean_absolute_error"]
    train_lrscores.append(hist * 100)
    lr_score = hist.score(X_val, y_val)
    lrscores.append(lr_score * 100)
```

Traceback:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py:302: UserWarning: ``build_fn`` will be renamed to ``model`` in a future release, at which point use of ``build_fn`` will raise an Error instead.
  "``build_fn`` will be renamed to ``model`` in a future release,"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_18384/2762271288.py in <module>
      3 for cv_train, cv_val in kfold.split(X_train, y_train):
      4     lr_model_logit = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_logistic_regression_model, batch_size = 10)
----> 5     hist = lr_model_logit.fit(X_train[cv_train], y_train[cv_train], epochs=200).history_
      6     losses = hist["mean_absolute_error"]
      7     train_lrscores.append(hist * 100)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)
   1492             sample_weight = 1 if sample_weight is None else sample_weight
   1493             sample_weight *= compute_sample_weight(class_weight=self.class_weight, y=y)
-> 1494         super().fit(X=X, y=y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **kwargs)
   1495         return self
   1496 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)
    765             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    766             warm_start=self.warm_start,
--> 767             **kwargs,
    768         )
    769 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py in _fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, warm_start, epochs, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    927         X = self.feature_encoder_.transform(X)
    928 
--> 929         self._check_model_compatibility(y)
    930 
    931         self._fit_keras_model(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py in _check_model_compatibility(self, y)
    549             # we recognize the attribute but do not force it to be
    550             # generated
--> 551             if self.n_outputs_expected_ != len(self.model_.outputs):
    552                 raise ValueError(
    553                     "Detected a Keras model input of size"

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

`X_train[cv_train]`

```
array([[ 3.49907650e-01,  1.01934833e+00,  9.22962131e-01, ...,
         4.65851423e-01,  5.85124577e-01, -2.30825406e-01],
       [-1.66145691e-01, -1.70198795e-01,  7.40812556e-01, ...,
        -1.25252966e-01,  6.11333541e-04, -1.85578709e+00],
       [-3.34532309e-01,  1.47744989e+00, -7.94889360e-01, ...,
         1.10431254e+00,  5.00866647e-01,  5.75451553e-01],
       ...,
       [-1.21341832e+00,  8.56729999e-01,  1.87070578e-01, ...,
        -8.38769062e-01, -7.08780127e-02, -6.54645722e-01],
       [ 3.45711192e-01,  8.01029131e-01,  9.37260745e-01, ...,
         6.35312010e-01, -1.77277404e-01, -1.05178867e+00],
       [ 1.65016194e+00,  1.34960903e+00,  1.17654404e+00, ...,
         3.79284887e-01,  4.38081218e-01, -3.55481467e-01]])
```

`y_train`

```
array([1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3,
       3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2,
       3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3,
       1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3,
       2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1,
       2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1,
       3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1,
       1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1,
       3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2,
       1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2,
       3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1,
       3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2,
       1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2,
       2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2,
       3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3,
       3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 3,
       2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a good look at your code and error before posting a question. Then if that does not help, thoroughly read the documentation.

[Keras fit() documentation](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/TensorFlow.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/KerasClassifier.html) -> What does .fit() return?

You have made a typo I believe. You expect the KerasClassifier object to have an attribute .history_. However this attribute is clearly None, looking at your error.

Be aware. Your typo will not help solving future requests, so it's better to look at existing questions in that case.

[Existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566791/keras-how-to-properly-use-fit-to-train-a-model)

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. I am migrating from `tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn` to `scikeras` as described in https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/migration.html#changes-to-your-code. In the documentation it is mentioned as `hist = clf.fit(...).history_`

Comment: Ah clear, is it possible that 'mean_absolute_error' does not exist in your history dictionary because your metric is 'accuracy'?